# PHP pagination without DB queries

Tags: php, pagination

I'm very newbie on this, I'm making simple pagination on PHP. 
There are many examples to making pagination with DB query, so I watched that several times, but couldn't find answer... I want to make it without DB queries.

So... Please imagine simple table.

[image]

very simple table. I want to separate above rows to 2 pages.
If I click 1st page, 
[image]

and 2nd page,

[image]

like that. How can I make it? Please help me...

```
<table>
<tr><th>Name</th> <th>Point</th></tr>
<tr><td>Row 1</td> <td>100</td><tr/>
<tr><td>Row 2</td> <td>200</td><tr/>
<tr><td>Row 3</td> <td>300</td><tr/>
<tr><td>Row 4</td> <td>400</td><tr/>
<tr><td>Row 5</td> <td>500</td><tr/>
<tr><td>Row 6</td> <td>600</td><tr/>
<tr><td>Row 7</td> <td>700</td><tr/>
<tr><td>Row 8</td> <td>800</td><tr/>
<tr><td>Row 9</td> <td>900</td><tr/>
<tr><td>Row 10</td> <td>1000</td><tr/>
```

Comment: If not a database, where does the information come from?

Comment: @jeroen The database come from php array variables... scrapping another site and parsing, saving variables to array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to paginate html table for this you can use jQuery plugin, which can be found under this URL

```
http://kayalshri.github.io/tablePagination/
```

You can check demo here

```
http://ngiriraj.com/pages/tablepagination/demo.php
```

Comment: Ohh... It is possible with jQuery. thanks a lot. I will try it right now.

Comment: @Juntae yes it is possible, jQuery will paginate the data on front end. (keep in mind it is not good for performance aspect if you are dealing with large rows). Vote up and accept the answer :) that would be appreciated